# H4 visa interview India: new I 797 but old stamp on passport

Tags: usa, india

I will be appearing for my H4 visa interview soon. My husband has had a H1-B transfer when he moved to a new job. His passport however still has the old stamp referring to his previous employer and the dates as applicable to the old H1-B.

Would my husband have to get his visa stamp renewed before I appear for the interview?

Note that I have all the documents from his new job i.e I 797, the I-129, employment verification, paystubs, W2.

Also, my husband had asked the immigration team and they said he did not have to get it restamped.

But I am a bit skeptical whether someone at the embassy might say something, like why does the passport not have the new stamp?

Please advise.

Comment: This is off topic for [Travel.SE].  I have flagged it for migration to [Expatriates.SE].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, he does not need a new visa. A US visa is only for entry, and if he doesn't need to enter, he doesn't need a visa. Your eligibility for H4 status and visa is based on his H1b status, not his visa.